# Could the Star Wars Universe survive without the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

After hearing about the upcoming Third Trilogy, I started to play with my imagination about what it could be about.

I think an interesting development could be borrowed from something I read in The Lord of The Rings. I'm not an expert there, but it is told that the era of the Elves is ending, as they are leaving the Middle Earth, and the era of Men is beginning.

I think it would be cool to tell about how Luke fulfilled the prophecy (to bring balance) up to its extreme end, and opened a new Era in which the Force has left the Galaxy forever. So no more Dark Side and Sith, but also no more Jedi. Every single being has now the power to make the difference. Optimistic vision and stuff like that :)

So here is my question: could this conflict with what was told up to this point? Could the Force leave the Galaxy?

Comment: Sure, and it's been done. (and we loved it.) Imagine if you took the Star Wars universe, removed the force and aliens, then set it a few hundred years in our future. Now, imagine if the Rebels lost, and Han Solo was flying around making a living as best he could. Then imagine that the TV show got cancelled and the fans loved it so much a movie got made.

Comment: I don't think its constructive because it's asking for opinions...

Comment: Depending on level of canon, this question has an answer:  [Yes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong)

Comment: @SachinShekhar I wasn't asking for opinions. I was asking if the story could develop that way without conflicting with estabilished elements. Nothing about opinions, personal taste etcetera. However, feel free to edit my question so that it fits.

Answer (score 6):

Star Wars Universe could, since according to canon it's the same Universe as ours, just a different Galaxy.

Comment: I would like to voice my opposition to your claim as I still believe the Force is powerful in *our* universe. We have, as @mh. commented merely lost our ability to use it. Perhaps we will one day regain its use.

Comment: @Mikhail I think we just don't have midichlorians, like the [Yuuzhan Vong](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yuuzhan_Vong)...

Comment: @Izkata- IIRC Vong didn't "not have midichlorians" since they USED to be connected to the Force till their planet cut them from it

Comment: @DVK Depends on _how_ they were cut off, I suppose...

Answer (score 6):

Let's ask Master Yoda:

> Life creates it, makes it grow. It's energy surrounds us and binds us. Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter.

My reading of this, and I'll admit that I may be wrong, is that the Force is actually a quite essential part of nature, and will spontaneously exist wherever life is.  So based on that the answer would be "no, it can't".

However, that's not the full story; let's see what Master Windu has to say:

> I think it is time to inform the senate that our ability to use the
>   force is diminished.

So a reasonable conclusion to draw from that is that while the universe *needs* the Force, the ability of those in the universe to actually *use* the Force could well go away.

Comment: I wonder though, could Yoda have just been biased in this regard? Maybe he gave the force too much credibility because he preferred the mysticism.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the canon from EU, this would never work. Disney would never make any money with a Star Wars film (let alone a trilogy) without the Force. So, no: The Force could not leave the Galaxy for financial reasons.

Comment: Not *really* an answer to the question. It wasn't "Would Disney make a Star Wars movie without the Force?"

Comment: @Xantec: Not in-universy enough?

Comment: Something like that. I'd say "no it isn't", but we're supposed to be in the same universe, so technically it is.

Comment: I think this is a thoroughly reasonable answer, albeit from a different way-of-looking

Comment: @ChristopherBerman- is that you, Obi-Wan?

Comment: I totally agree with you. In fact, in the hypothetic story arc a was imagining (and which inspired my question), the Force would leave at the very end of the trilogy, so there would be no movie without the Force.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what you mean by survival of universe.

- If you mean in-universe removal of the Force from Galaxy: Existence of the Force can't be controlled. But, if all force-sensitives go out of Galaxy, the Force can be ignored fully. Without a force user, the Force can't be observed because Science and Technology can't measure it. The world would seem like normal real world. And, the universe can survive.
- If you mean removal of the Force from story arc of out-of-universe commercial canon: With slight changes to story, the universe can survive, but I doubt the universe would survive commercially. I don't want to discuss it because it's off-topic here (not constructive).